# Tomcat 7 upgrade

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I tried to upgrade my Java EE application from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7. Everything is working fine on my PC (Windows XP 32 bit with 32 bit JVM, JDK 1.6).

But when I configured another Windows machine with a 32 bit JVM, Tomcat started, but when I tried to access the application I got a 404 error.

In the log file I got the following:

> APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;

I also got the following:

> INFO: Server startup in 4581 ms Nov 30, 2012 11:59:25 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies processCookieHeader INFO: Cookies:
>   Invalid cookie. Value not a token or quoted value  Note: further
>   occurrences of Cookie errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Just upgrade the current jre to jre7.Your Problem will be solved.If not upgrade the jdk also.This is only related to version conflict.You may  be compiling your files with latest jdk and try to run with old jre.

Answer (score 2):

APR - just ignore, that's saying that you are using java binaries instead of system native. They (are supposed to) work the same. Natives are important for production.

Regarding the cookie error: This is what helps with JBoss AS 7: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1625

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true
```